# C++::How to put different length arrays of const strings into common class

Tags: c++

Sorry, new to C++, converting from C, and have struggled to find a good way to do this...

//Fragment follows

```
const char *List1[]={"Choice1", "Not a good choice", "choice3"}; //rom-able
const char *List2[]={"Hello", "Experts", "Can", "You", "Help?"};

class ListIF{
private:
 int index;
 char *list;
public:
  void GetValString(char *tgt,int len);//get parameter value as string max len chars
  void SetIndex(int n){index = n;};
  int  GetIndex(void){return index;};
};
```

//end Fragment

The problem is how to write the constructor so that I can "encapsulate" the lists inside the class, without getting heap bloat (embedded target).  And then how to write the gettor so that we can see list[index] within the class.

I am going daft trying to do something that seems obvious, so I am missing something?

Comment: Sounds like you want to make the lists static members of the class, that way they get shared across all instances of the class.

Comment: I so not fully understand your problem. Can you describe what you are actually trying to achieve? What is `ListIF` supposed to be used for?

Comment: How is `GetValString` is going to be used? can you give an example?

Comment: Basic idea is dynamic menu structure.
    ListIF MyMenu[4] =  {Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4};

    for (i=0;i<4;i++){ cout<<MyMenu[i].GetValstring();};
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want your functions to be but one way to wrap the arrays would be:

EDIT : changed to incorporate Larsmans suggestion (on the chance that your compiler can't handle his answer).

```
class ListIF
{
private:
    std::vector<const char*> m_list;//stores ptrs to the ROM
public:

    ListIF(char const **list, size_t n) : m_list(list, list+n) {}

    const char* get( int pos )
    {
        return m_list[pos];
    }
};
```

Comment: Or: `ListIF(char const **list, size_t n) : m_list(list, list+n) {}`

Comment: Now it won't work because the ctor name doesn't match the class name.

Comment: Nice. Makes sense.  Will use. :)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, prefer using `std::string` over `const char*`. It will solve most of your problems you face with `const char*`.

For an array of strings, use `std::vector<std::string>`. It will solve most of your problems you face with `const char *[]`.

You can even initialize the `std::vector` with multiple strings as,

```
std::vector<std::string> List1(adder<std::string>("Choice1")("Not a good choice")("choice3"));
std::vector<std::string> List2(adder<std::string>("Hello")("Experts")("Can")("You")("Help?"));
```

Where `adder<>` is a class template defined as:

```
template<typename T>
struct adder
{
   std::vector<T> items;
   adder(const T &item) { items.push_back(item); }
   adder& operator()(const T & item) { items.push_back(item); return *this; }
   operator std::vector<T>&() { return items ; }
};
```

Sample running code here : http://www.ideone.com/GLEZr

Comment: The OP wants to use literals in ROM memory. `std::string` will make a copy in RAM.

Comment: @larsmans: But it may be possible to use a custom allocator to handle that.

Comment: Might do that...keeping it simple atm.  End product has GUI with unicode handling, so datatype will need to change anyway. Ta.

Comment: @Nick: If you want unicode, then you can use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/** Wrapper for C style arrays; does not take ownership of the array */
template <typename T>
class static_array
{
    T *array;
    size_t nelems;

  public:
    template <size_t N>
    static_array(T (&a)[N]) : array(a), nelems(N) {}

    T &operator[](size_t i) { return array[i]; }
    T const &operator[](size_t i) const { return array[i]; }
    size_t size() const { return nelems; }
};

typedef static_array<char const *> static_cstr_array;
```

Construct as `static_cstr_array array1(List1)`. The setter is `operator[]`, i.e.

```
array1[1] = "foo!";
```

You can add any method that you want to this class.

(I chose the name `static_array` because, as far as the class is concerned, the underlying array must be static: it should not grow, shrink or move due to `realloc` or otherwise. It doesn't mean the array must have static linkage.)

Comment: Should you have a setter function? The list is constant (and ROM) but your setter (running under VS2005) appears to overwrite the array (although it doesn't affect other objects initialised to the same array).

Comment: @Patrick: in the OP's example, the array itself is not `const`, only the strings it contains.

Comment: thanks...I tried templating for size_t, but couldn't derive classes from the template.  Good code, though.

Comment: @Nick: what do you mean, couldn't derive classes from it?